# Merging with notify-osd

Tags: ayatana, libnotify

I've written a program that uses Notify-OSD but occasionally messages from my app will stack up in the queue. I've read about [Notify-OSD merging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Merging%20notifications) However, it doesn't do this automatically - how can I get my application to merge notifications so they don't stream in one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate related notifications bubbles by setting the hint string `x-canonical-append` to `true`.

```
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init('test')

n = Notify.Notification.new('Summary', 'Line 1', 'dialog-information')
n.set_hint_string('x-canonical-append', 'true')
n.show()

n = Notify.Notification.new('Summary', 'Line 2', 'dialog-information')
n.set_hint_string('x-canonical-append', 'true')
n.show()
```

For more details see `append-hint-python.py` python example at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/notify-osd/trunk/view/head:/examples/append-hint-example.py

Source: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/#Concatenating_related_notification_bubbles

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing in python use the update method of the notification object then the show method:

```
notification = pynotify.Notification("title", "body", "icon")
notification.show()
#later
notification.update("title2", "body2", "icon2")
notification.show()
```

If you are developing in C, there is the [notify_notification_update()](http://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/0.7/NotifyNotification.html#notify-notification-update) function that does the same thing. Other languages will be similar but the naming may be slightly different.